# Navigation Drawer is not opening when sliding from left

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

As the page on Android Developers says

> The user can bring the navigation drawer onto the screen by swiping from the left edge of the screen or by touching the application icon on the action bar.

But strangely the navigation drawer on my activity does not respond to sliding action. It toggles only on touching the icon on the action bar. Below is my implementation of the navigation drawer

```
 mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);

    // Set up the drawer.
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            drawerLayout);
```

Is there any possible explanation for this? What I doubt is my activity by default has the layout of one of its fragments. So is that the reason?

Edit: The layout file of my activity

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainPage">

<!-- The main ocntent view -->
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>


<!-- The navigation drawer-->
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:name="com.example.android.handsfree.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

Comment: Can you provide your layout file ?

Comment: Can you close the drawer with a sliding gesture ?

Comment: No. I can close the drawer either by touching the icon on action bar or touching the content outside the navigation drawer

Comment: What class is your MainPage Activity extending ? 
Can you post the code of your NavigationDrawerFragment (maybe via [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) beacuase it may be very long)

Comment: MainPage is extending `ActionBarActivity`

[This](http://pastebin.com/Vymya2BT) is the `NavigationDrawerFragment` class

Comment: The `NavigationDrawerFragment` looks fine to me. 
You are using the support Toolbar, right ? 
I can't see it inside the layout ?
Is there any "special" content shown in the container ? 
Would you mind to provide the code of your `MainPage` ?

Comment: Yes, I am using v7. [This](http://pastebin.com/bkJR3WT2) is the `MainPage` Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ´NavigationDrawerFragment´ already creates a drawer Toggle for you inside its `setUp´ method.

You should **not** create a new one inside your ´MainPage´ Activity.

---

Notes:
You can use the `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` instead of the **v4** one inside the `NavigationDrawerFragment`.

---

## Update:

The problem seems solved now. There were 2 Issues:

1. The OP created a second drawer toggle in it's `MainPage` - Activity but there was already one created inside the `NavigationDrawerFragment`'s setUp method, which gets called by the MainPage in order to set up the drawer. (This is basicly outsourc[ecoding]ing some of the drawer stuff to the drawer fragment.)
2. The OP locked the drawer inside `onCreateOptionsMenu` by calling a method which sets the DrawerLockMode to `LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED`. He never reverted this change.

Comment: Where is your toolbar inside the layout ? 
In one of the above comments you said you are using the Toolbar widget. `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

Comment: Instead of using the Android ActionBar the support library is using it's **own** toolbar view/widget (See my My Layout as an **example** [Here](http://pastebin.com/pLyBq61n)

Comment: I guess importing it is not the only thing to do, right? How do I "use" the support library?

Comment: you are already using it I assume. DrawerLayout is part of it. It is just a bunch of additional calsses and resources which is extending or providing backward compatibility of the normal android.

Comment: But try it without the Toolbar part first.

Comment: Okay. For trying without the Toolbar part, I need to use v7 instead of v4 in `NavigationDrawerFragment`
Other than that, I need to remove the drawer toggle from `MainPage`, right?

Comment: Try fist with just removing the toggle from the MainPage.
Line 61-90 , 121 , 127 , 204,208
**AND** Do not use line 211 `drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(drawerMode);` because you are setting the drawer mode to  `LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED` from line 188,But never reverting it !

Comment: App force closed. Log cat:

`01-31 19:27:25.206  10313-10313/com.example.android.effectivenavigation E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.effectivenavigation/com.example.android.handsfree.MainPage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)`

Comment: [This](http://pastebin.com/avyh2F8E) is the `MainPage`
[This](http://pastebin.com/6Lnar08j) is the `NavigationDrawerFragment`
[This](http://pastebin.com/RsDNWXt4) is the logcat

Comment: Edit: I used log messages to find out that the toggle methods of `MainPage` are actually being invoked instead of those in `NavigationDrawerFragment` during toggle state changes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69953/discussion-between-xyaren-and-rockydgeekgod).

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);

Comment: The drawer should be unlocked by default after creation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/drawer"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

on your activity

```
drawlayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    listData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_drawer);

    drawlayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);
```

Comment: How will this solve the problem ? 
The OP uses a fragment a a drawer which is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes. The doc in Android Developers says we can use a `ListView` but it is not the only way.

Comment: so you have to use ActionBarDrawableToggle for that so u can use any other layout instead of ListView.

Comment: it is apply in api-21

Answer (score 0):

Add these fields in your activity class:

```
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
```

Then, inside your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true)

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

`ic_drawer` is a `.png` image which located in drawable resources. You can search this image on Google.

API level to be used is 11+.

Hope it helps for you.

Comment: The constructor you have used for `ActionBarDrawerToggle` is for `v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`. 
What I am using is `v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`

So, there is no parameter for a drawable
[This](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) is the link

Comment: What is the difference or the advantages?

Answer (score 0):

1- replace the  tag by :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainPage">

    <!-- The main ocntent view -->
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>


    <!-- The navigation drawer-->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

2- use this code in the onCreate function u can use the v4 ActionBarDrawerToggle or the v7 her i use the v4:

```
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,    mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_drawer,
R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name) {
                    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                        invalidateOptionsMenu();
                    }

                    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                        getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                        invalidateOptionsMenu();
                    }
                };
                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Comment: I have used the v7 version. But other than that I can see see no difference between your and my code